# Can I aggregate with parameters taken from data frame?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, aggregate

I'd like to perform different aggregations in a loop to be applied to different row subsets of my data, but it seems tricky to achieve (if possible at all):

```
t <- data.frame(agg=c(list("field1"=field1, "field2"=field2), ...),
                fun=c(mean, ...))
f <- function(x) {
    for (i in 1:nrow(t) {
        y <- aggregate(x, by=t$agg[i], FUN=t$fun[i])
        # do something with y
    }
}
```

One problem is that the field list `agg` triggers an error when trying to build the data frame ("*object 'field1' not found*"), and the other problem is that R does not like to assign a function value to `fun` ("*cannot coerce class ""function"" to a data.frame*").

**Appendix:**
A concrete example for my data (just to match the definitions above) could be:

```
> d <- data.frame(field1=round(rnorm(5, 10, 1)),field2=letters[round(rnorm(5, 10, 1))], field3=1:5)
> d
  field1 field2 field3
1     11      j      1
2     11      i      2
3     10      j      3
4     12      i      4
5     11      j      5
> with(d, aggregate(d$field3,by=list(field1, field2),FUN=mean))
  Group.1 Group.2 x
1      11       i 2
2      12       i 4
3      10       j 3
4      11       j 3
```

Playing tricks with the variable names in the data frame, I still get this:

```
> with(d,t <- data.frame(agg=c(list("field1"=field1, "field2"=field2)),fun=c(mean)))
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ""function"" to a data.frame
```

Comment: `by` argument should have a vector of the same length as `x`. Is this condition satisfied? Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Why would you use a data frame for this instead of a list?

Comment: @Leo P: Does _"Why would you use a data frame for this instead of a list?"_ mean that you have a solution for a list?

Comment: Well, considering that you can save any object into a list (like functions for example) without being constrained by the limitations of a data frame, it seems the obvious choice. You should build your function to include multiple variables: Let `by` and `FUN` be defined by the function call instead of fixing it within the function. `f <- function(var, data, group1, group2,  fun) {... with(data, aggregate(data[, var], by = list(data[, c(group1, group2)], FUN = fun)) ...}` would be the better approach in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

The problems were several, mostly caused by R making exceptions to general processing:

- First a vector cannot be nested, but only lists can.  Still all the elements are required to have the same type.
- Second, `data.frame` does some magic treatment when constructing the variables (causing the inability to assign closures), so it cannot be used.
- Finally I had to refer to variables to aggregate by name

So the definition looks like this (where `, ...` means "add more similar items"):

```
t <- list(agg=list(c("field1", "field2"), ...),
          fun=list(mean, ...))

f <- function(x) {
    for (i in 1:length(t$agg)) {
        agg <- t$agg[[i]]
        aggList <- lapply(agg, FUN=function(e) x[[e]])
        names(aggList) <- agg
        y <- aggregate(x, by=aggList, FUN=t$fun[[i]])
        # do something with y
    }
}
```

Note: In the actual solution I added another list holding the names of the columns to select for the aggregated data frame to avoid warnings about `mean` returning `NA`.